# Some wp-admin folder file deleted when Wordpress upgrade

Tags: updates

We upgrading Wordpress then some custom files deleted from wp-admin folder. but theme/template file not deleted.

Comment: What kind of "custom files"? Have you modified WordPress core?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż, we create some custom file ie. custom contact us form report from admin

Comment: And have you put these files in wp-admin directory?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż, yes

Comment: @Soundararajanm don't put any custom files in wp-admin or wp-includes directories. Create a site-based plugin for this. Please follow this guide for creating plugin : https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Answer (score 6):

Both `wp-includes` and `wp-admin` folders contain core files of WordPress. You should never modify any of them, because it is crucial for WP to be able to change these folders during updates.

Almost the same is true for all WP files placed in root folder - `wp-config.php` is the only file that WP won’t overwrite for sure.

All your custom code should be placed in `wp-content` folder. But... To be more precise - the theme files should go into `wp-content/themes` and they should only define how the site looks, and all other functions should be coded as plugins and placed in `wp-content/plugins`.

And yes - if you modify any of core directories/files, then you’ll face this problem of overwriting after every update of WP.